# Use HTTPS with Basic Auth in Swagger securitySchemes

Tags: https, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, basic-authentication

I have this app where I am using Swagger to show it's endpoints. I use Basic Auth and I wanted Swagger UI to make the HTTP Requests in the "Try it out" with HTTPS because of security.

In the [Swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/basic-authentication/#:%7E:text=This%20scheme%20must%20have%20type%3A%20http) it says

> This scheme must have type: http

but then, does it mean that there is no way to make a safe request using Basic Auth? I understand that the authentication method itself is "weak", but I read that it behaves like a form POST when using HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have confused some OpenAPI keywords and HTTP concepts.

`type: http` in `securitySchemes` refers to the *authentication method*, in this case [HTTP authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication), which refers to the use of the `Authorization` HTTP request header to send the credentials. Basic authentication is one of the implementations of HTTP authentication.

The `http://` or `https://` part of request URLs is the [*protocol*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Identifying_resources_on_the_Web#syntax_of_uniform_resource_identifiers_uris). In OpenAPI 3, the protocol is defined as part of `servers` URLs. In OpenAPI 2.0, it's defined using the `schemes` keyword. For details, see:

- [API Server and Base URL](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/) guide for OpenAPI 3.0
- [API Host and Base URL](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/) guide for OpenAPI 2.0

#### Example

A request to https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd sent over HTTPS with Basic authentication can be defined as follows in OpenAPI 3.0:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: HTTPS + Basic auth example
  version: 1.0.0

servers:
  - url: https://httpbin.org

components:
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
      description: Use `user` / `passwd` as the test credentials

paths:
  /basic-auth/user/passwd:
    get:
      security:
        - basicAuth: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized. The username or password provided is incorrect.
```